# T-SQL query getting the max of a sub element

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, window-functions

Consider a table like this:

| Category | Subcategory | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Apple | i1 |
| Foo | Apple | i2 |
| Foo | Apple | i3 |
| Foo | Pear | i4 |
| Foo | Pear | i5 |
| Bar | Blackberry | i6 |
| Bar | Blueberry | i7 |
| Bar | Blueberry | i8 |

I want to, for each `category`, get the `subcategory` with the highest count of `item`s. I don't care about the identity of the items (or even their count). So, I'd expect the final return to be

| Category | Subcategory |
| --- | --- |
| Foo | Apple |
| Bar | Blueberry |

I've tried

```sql
WITH pool AS (
    SELECT
        category,
        subcategory,
        COUNT(item) AS "itemCount"
    FROM table
    GROUP BY category, subcategory
),
maxItems AS (
    SELECT
        category,
        MAX(subcategory), -- In real life, this is a numeric column
    FROM pool
    GROUP BY category
    HAVING itemCount = MAX(itemCount)
)
-- and final query here filtered on the category -> subcategory mapping from above
```

but the HAVING statement errors with

> `is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Of *course* it's not in the group by. I don't want to group by the max count, I want to *filter* by it.

I can make it work with a subquery in maxItems, changing it to

```sql
maxItems AS (
    SELECT
        category,
        MAX(subcategory), -- In real life, this is a numeric column
    FROM pool
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            subcategory,
            MAX(itemCount) AS "itemCount"
        FROM pool
        GROUP BY subcategory
    ) AS "maxFilter"
        ON rmCounts.subcategory = maxFilter.subcategory
        AND maxFilter.itemCount = rmCounts.itemCount
    GROUP BY category
)
```

but I really feel like it'd be more elegant and more clear if `HAVING` worked, and I don't understand why it *doesn't*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I accepted an answer already, but I didn't particularly care about ties, a random pick would have been fine. 

@Charlieface you know, I know how to do that and it just straight up didn't occur to me to approach the question that way -- it wasn't the way the metaphor was built up in my head. Thanks! (I think the `FIRST_VALUE` below by forpas is a more syntactically clear solution though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Category,
       FIRST_VALUE(Subcategory) OVER (PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) Subcategory
FROM tablename 
GROUP BY Category, Subcategory;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=87c092b0fa46a2cb58aa7cfcd734602c).

Comment: Ooh, that's tidy

Answer (score 3):

here is one way, which handles ties as well :

```
select * from (
   select category,Subcategory,rank() over (partition by category order by count(*) desc) rn 
   from tablename
   group by category,Subcategory
)t where rn = 1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32ac319714d570bb6fd901c149a6adc0)*

Answer (score 0):

This gets the highest of each subcategory, and returns two subcategories if the counts tie:

```
select a.category, a.subcategory, itemcounts.total
from table a
cross apply ( select top 1 b.subcategory, count(b.item) as total
            from table b 
            where b.category = a.category
            group by b.subcategory
            order by count(b.item) desc) itemcounts
group by a.category, a.subcategory, itemcounts.total
having count(a.item) = itemcounts.total
```